# How do I change one of my fields according to the result of a subquery, Error: Subquery returned more than 1 value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

What I want to do is a query that indicates the projects that are found within a table and that are average rate once you have such projects of the query what I have to do is that through another query I can multiply a percentage to a field from another table where that same project should exist.

```
select CASE
    WHEN estimador.Clave = 'Perfiles' THEN (select gasto.[Importe Banco]*0.5 from SN_INT_PartidasGasto as gasto where gasto.[Clase de Coste]='FSW' and estimador.IdProyecto=gasto.[ID Proyecto] and AmbientePRE='PRE')
    WHEN estimador.Clave = 'Puntos V1' THEN 'Puntos V1'
    WHEN estimador.Clave = 'Puntos V2' THEN 'Puntos V2'
    ELSE 'Sorry, no match.'
    END AS CATEGORIA from tb_Estimador as estimador where estimador.IdProyecto in (select gse.FolioSantec from db_Incurrido.dbo.GSE_Real as gse where gse.FolioSantec=estimador.IdProyecto and estimador.Clave!='Tarifa Promedio')
```

With the query above I get the following error:

```
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= ,
>, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

Answer (score 2):

Subquery at the select part returns more than 1 row. You should add `top 1` to it.

```
select CASE
    WHEN estimador.Clave = 'Perfiles' THEN (select TOP 1 gasto.[Importe Banco]*0.5 from SN_INT_PartidasGasto as gasto where gasto.[Clase de Coste]='FSW' and estimador.IdProyecto=gasto.[ID Proyecto] and AmbientePRE='PRE')
    WHEN estimador.Clave = 'Puntos V1' THEN 'Puntos V1'
    WHEN estimador.Clave = 'Puntos V2' THEN 'Puntos V2'
    ELSE 'Sorry, no match.'
    END AS CATEGORIA from tb_Estimador as estimador where estimador.IdProyecto 
    in (select gse.FolioSantec from db_Incurrido.dbo.GSE_Real as gse where gse.FolioSantec=estimador.IdProyecto and estimador.Clave!='Tarifa Promedio')
```

Comment: I think this is the most sensible solution given the information in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `APPLY` with `JOIN`:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN estimador.Clave = 'Perfiles' 
             THEN gasto.[Importe Banco] * 0.5
             WHEN estimador.Clave = 'Puntos V1' 
             THEN 'Puntos V1'
             WHEN estimador.Clave = 'Puntos V2' 
             THEN 'Puntos V2' 
             ELSE 'Sorry, no match.'
        END) AS CATEGORIA 
FROM tb_Estimador as estimador INNER JOIN
     db_Incurrido.dbo.GSE_Real AS gse
     ON gse.FolioSantec = estimador.IdProyecto OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT TOP (1) gasto.[Importe Banco] 
      FROM SN_INT_PartidasGasto AS gasto 
      WHERE gasto.[Clase de Coste] = 'FSW' AND 
            estimador.IdProyecto = gasto.[ID Proyecto] AND 
            AmbientePRE = 'PRE'
     ) gasto 
WHERE estimador.Clave <> 'Tarifa Promedio';
```